# When I'm using UISwipeGestureRecognizer I'm getting Thread 1:Signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, ios8, sigabrt, gestures, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i exactly wrote the code as a youtube video tutorial for training purposes. this is the second program i make with the same error. is something wrong with my iOS simulator ?

here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self,action: Selector("handleSwipes"))
     var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self,action: Selector("handleSwipes"))
     var upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self,action: Selector("handleSwipes"))
     var downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self,action: Selector("handleSwipes"))

    leftSwipe.direction = .Left
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    upSwipe.direction = .Up
    downSwipe.direction = .Down

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    if (sender.direction == .Left){
        Label.text = "Left"
    }
    if (sender.direction == .Right){
        Label.text = "Right"
    }
    if (sender.direction == .Up){
        Label.text = "Up"
    }
    if (sender.direction == .Down){
        Label.text = "Down"
    }
}
```

}

the error is:

> 2015-08-03 15:13:09.545 SwipeGestures[14088:457164]
>   -[SwipeGestures.ViewController handleSwipes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79f92120 2015-08-03 15:13:09.550
>   SwipeGestures[14088:457164] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[SwipeGestures.ViewController handleSwipes]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x79f92120'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x002a9466 **exceptionPreprocess + 182  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x01c98a97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x002b12c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x001f9bc7 ___forwarding_** + 1047
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x001f978e
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   UIKit                               0x00f05057 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 327    6   UIKit
>   0x00f038d4 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
>   + 561     7   UIKit                               0x00f0591d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60    8   UIKit                               0x00f0929a **_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke661 + 57    9
>
>   UIKit                               0x00f0915d
>   _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317    10  UIKit                               0x00efd066
>   _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 3720     11  UIKit                               0x00b14c5b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356    12  UIKit
>
>   0x00b15abf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769   13  UIKit
>
>   0x00adabb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242  14  UIKit
>
>   0x00aeabf6 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21066    15  UIKit 
>   0x00abebc7 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300  16  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x001cc98f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  17  CoreFoundation                      0x001c249d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253  18  CoreFoundation                      0x001c19f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x001c137b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443     20  CoreFoundation
>   0x001c11ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   21  GraphicsServices
>   0x0404e2c1 GSEventRunModal + 192  22  GraphicsServices
>   0x0404e0fe GSEventRun + 104   23  UIKit
>   0x00ac29b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526   24  SwipeGestures
>   0x000c2e1e top_level_code + 78    25  SwipeGestures
>   0x000c2e5b main + 43  26  libdyld.dylib
>   0x02406ac9 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a colon after method's name:

`Selector("handleSwipes:")`

It's because handleSwipes has an argument in its definition.

Comment: ill upvote your answer once i am allowed to ... still less than 15!

Answer (score 3):

Replace your gesture code with below one,

```
    var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipes:")
    var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipes:")
    var upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipes:")
    var downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipes:")
```

Comment: im not allowed to uproot yet since i have less than 15 reputation points

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a delegate:

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the delegate for the UISwipeGestureRecognizer. e.g:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

And:

```
leftSwipe.delegate = self
```

And implement:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

If it still fails, add a colon in the selector name as suggested by someone else.

If you use the following tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial you can also read that if you have multiple gesture recognizers, you need the delegate. By default only 1 is allowed.

Comment: yes will use it in the future man... ill upvote your answer once i am allowed to ... still less than 15!